# Django model form ImproperlyConfigured error

Tags: python, django, forms, class

> ImproperlyConfigured: Creating a ModelForm without either the 'fields'
>   attribute or the 'exclude' attribute is prohibited; form
>   CustomUserChangeForm needs updating.

```
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm
from login1.models import CustomUser


class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserCreationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
       model = CustomUser
       fields = ("email",)

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
```

Comment: and were i could check the error?

Comment: That error appears to tell you *exactly* what is wrong and what to change. What is confusing about it?

Answer (score 1):

When you create a ModelForm it expecting you to specify what fields to show in template i.e) when you do {{ form }} in html you would expect some fields to render right? So in this case you have specify the fields attribute.

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):      
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)       
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__' or ['your_field']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define within `CustomUserChangeForm.Meta` class that what model fields should be included in form:

```
class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kargs):
        super(CustomUserChangeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kargs)
        del self.fields['username']

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = '__all__'  #<-- add this or name fields you want to include as sequence
```